# Detecting SignalR authorize failures from web client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm experimenting with SignalR hosted in an asp.net MVC5 application and am having an issue detecting authorization failures from a web client.

I have a simple hub as follows:

```
public class ChitChat : Hub
{
    [Authorize]
    public string Hi(string incoming)
    {
        Clients.All.echo(incoming);

        return "Echoed " + incoming;
    }
}
```

And on the web page:

```
    $(function() {
        var hub = $.connection.chitChat;

        hub.client.echo = function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                console.log("Done starting hub");

                hub.server.hi("Client message")
                    .done(function() {
                        console.log(arguments);
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log(arguments);
                    });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("Fail hub" + arguments);
            });
    });
```

When I enable detailed errors in the hub configuration, I get this in the promise rejection for hi

```
Error: Caller is not authorized to invoke the Hi method on ChitChat.
```

Without detailed errors, I just get

```
Error: There was an error invoking Hub method 'chitchat.Hi'.
```

I'd like to keep detailed errors off, but still get some dependable way of identifying auth failures (I'd assumed I would get a 401/403 code somewhere). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you managed to find a way of achieving this? I am trying to do the same too.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR uses jQuery under the hood, so detecting the 401 status code could be achieved by following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            // your code is here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a rejection r, check r.source.status. This should give you a 401/403 when it is an authorization problem.